# Azure DevOps Extensions - Change extension category

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

So I have an Azure DevOps extension that I made and it appears in the "Repos" category:

[Repos category](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nmt23.png)

I want it to appear in the "Pipelines" category:

[Pipelines category](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8XIe.png)

I already changed my vss-extension.json "categories" attribute to this:

[vss-extension.json "categories" attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1T2B.png)

But it keeps appearing in the Repos tab.

Any idea if I can change this? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the **contributions filed** in vss-extension.json.

The targets:`ms.vss-build-web.build-release-hub-group` will show the extension in the Pipelines tab.

Here is an example:

```
  "contributions": [
        {
            "id": "my-hub",
            "type": "ms.vss-web.hub",
            "targets": [
                "ms.vss-build-web.build-release-hub-group"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "name": "My Hub",
                "uri": "my-hub.html"
            }
        }
    ],
```

**Result:**

[image]

Categories field  is used to distinguish categories type of extension.

For example:

[image]